# Create a JCheckBox with text as columnName but value as "schema.table.columnname"

Tags: java, swing, jcheckbox

I have a JCheckBox, where I need the value different from the Text displayed as processing needs some other name and the name to be displayed is a shorter name.

The only method I saw for `JCheckBox` is `setText("Text")` which just handles the display part.

Comment: A little unclear what you're asking. A `JCheckBox` can store a value of `boolean` and can display any `String`. I assume you want its initial value read from database?

Comment: No, I want the JTextBox to display a name say "Kat" and behind the scenes I want it to save the value "Katrina" some thing like in the J2EE TextField

Comment: Any particular reason why not use text field?

Comment: Yes, I need multiple selection so Need a JChekbox List for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `JCheckBox` has a value of `boolean` and can display any `String`.

Its value (which is its *selected* state) can be set/get using the `isSelected()` and `setSelected()` methods.

Its displayed text can be set/get using the `getText()` and `setText()` methods.

If you want to store another `String` value for it, you can use its `getName()` and `setName()` methods.

If you need to store more values in the component and/or not just `String`s, take a look at the [putClientProperty()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#putClientProperty-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-) and [getClientProperty()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getClientProperty-java.lang.Object-) methods. Using these you can store any values associated with keys (provided by you):

> The get/putClientProperty methods provide access to a small per-instance hashtable.